# Howto: the minimal server to serve zero length answers

Tags: performance, static, nginx, web

I face funny problem: I have an FreeBSD 8.2 server, and I need to set up web server that wil answer zero (0) length answer to any request. Just '200 OK' and zero body.

Ok, I can setup nginx (and already did that) and set 404 error document to /dev/null, but I think maybe there is more optimal and elegant solution? I know there is nginx module that output 1x1 gif, may there be anything like that for zero-length file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to return a status code from Nginx:

```
location /empty {
  return 200;
}
```

**NOTE** Generally, HTTP status code `204 No Content` is meant to say "I've completed the request, but there is no body to return". You may return it in the same fashion:

```
location /empty {
  return 204;
}
```

Comment: To return an HTTP `200` status static content w/ NGINX can be done like this: ```location = /empty { return 200 " "; }``` too. But like @alexander-azarof said, its better to send a `204`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use netcat like in the example here http://howtoforge.com/useful-uses-of-netcat

E.g.

```
while true; do echo 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
' | nc -l  80; done
```

Comment: In fact, pretty nice. Just forget about netcat, thanks for pointing out that!